# How to click on a link with an anchor tag on a page through selenium webdriver and java

Tags: html, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, css-selectors

```
<a href="https://www.pharmacistexcellence.com/index/aboutpep#pepLinkSection">
    <img class="iconBulletLink" style="vertical-align:middle; position: relative; top: -1px;" src="https://www.pharmacistexcellence.com/assets/images/icon-bullet.png" width="25">        
</a>

<div style="vertical-align:middle; display:inline;" class="anchr sixthAnch beforeAnch afterAnch">
About PEP
</div>
```

What type of locator can I use?

Comment: How are we supposed to answer without any details? Please share actual codes related to your question(if necessarry) and details about your problem, be more specific. Also, read [How Do I ask Good Questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

As per the *HTML* you have shared to click on the link you can use either of the following *Locator Strategies* (*Java perspective*):

- *cssSelector* :

  ```
  driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("a[href='https://www.pharmacistexcellence.com/index/aboutpep#pepLinkSection']>img.iconBulletLink")).click();
  ```
- *xpath* :

  ```
  driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@href='https://www.pharmacistexcellence.com/index/aboutpep#pepLinkSection']/img[@class='iconBulletLink']")).click();
  ```